# How To Maintain The Bottom Border Color Displayed When A Primefaces Commandbutton Is Clicked?

Tags: css, primefaces, commandbutton

I have 3 command buttons that filters a datatable and I want to keep the bottom border active to indicate which button was clicked.

So far, what I've done in a CSS is:

```
.ui-button.ui-state-hover, .ui-button.ui-state-active {
  border-bottom-color: #ccff00;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: thick;
}
```

Using the above CSS, when I hover over a button, the color of the bottom border changes, as expected;  but when I click the button, the color of the bottom border doesn't keep activated and the button go back in its original normal state.

Does anyone knows how can I do to keep the color of the bottom border in a button last clicked ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post more code or a codepen of the button to see the problem? I feel like it has to do with Visited or Active or Focus state.

Comment: Ok GrandIQ. See my updated question if it is enough code now ok? Thanks.

Comment: So you want it to maintain the effect after the hover is removed?

Comment: I  just want to maintain the color of the bottom border when the button is clicked.

Comment: Sadly the only way to do that is combining css and javascript, are you willing to use a little JavaScript or even for simpler use jQuery to achieve this? You need to attach a custom class name on click so that it retains those effects.

Comment: Anything that works is fine.

Comment: What is **your**  definition for active, since the jquery/PrimeFaces definition is 'during the period it is the trigger of performing some (server side) action' and it does that with your css. Normally the css for hover and active are not identical for a good reason

Comment: If you just want to do it client-side (not survive an F5  refresh) use the 'onstart' of a commandButton, add a class to the current button and remove the class of all the other buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the goal of leaving the border the same color after clicking it, we need to use Javascript to append or attach a new class

This is also using jQuery for quickness.

```js
$(".btn").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin:50px;
}

button {
  padding:20px;
  border:4px solid #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  color:#333;
  transition.5s;
}

button:hover {
  border-bottom-color:red;
  transition:.5s;
}

.active {
  border-bottom-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Click Me!</button>
<button class="btn">Click Me!</button>
<button class="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

Now the active class will be attached onto the button as long as the page is not refreshed/reloaded. If you want to remove the class simply check on click again and see if the class is attached, if so remove it and repeat.

Comment: So after a few clicks on different buttons, all have this class and look identical? ;-)

Comment: Yes, because I am using $(this) attribute so that it only targets the button that is clicked. I also updated the answer to use a proper $(.classname).

Comment: [grandiq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7711818/grandiq), I've made a few modifications, but your answer helped me a lot to resolve it. Thank you!